# spark streaming avro decoder for kafka avro messages in python

Tags: python, apache-spark, apache-kafka, streaming, avro

I am using pyspark api to read the avro messages which is throwing me an exception saying the default decoder(utf8_decoder) cant resolve the data. can anyone help resolve this issue. I have tried to install confluent schema registry client which I am not comfortable with. I would like to know if there is any other way to read avro encoded messages.

here is the code I am using.

```
sc = SparkContext("local[2]","myConsumer")
ssc = StreamingContext(sc, streamingIntervalSecs)

kafkaParams = {"metadata.broker.list":brokers, 'auto.offset.reset' : 'smallest' , "group.id" : consumerGroupID }

directKafkaStream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(ssc, [topic], kafkaParams, fromOffsets())

ssc.start()
ssc.awaitTermination()
```

Please let me know if any one have a solution for this.

Note: I would like to know if there are any other solutions other than this([Spark Python Avro Kafka Deserialiser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30339636/spark-python-avro-kafka-deserialiser)) and if you feel this is the best solution, I am also working on installing the schema registry and trying to work with it.

Thanks!

Comment: What's wrong with this solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30339636/spark-python-avro-kafka-deserialiser ?

Comment: I am new to python and spark, I found it a little complex to install confluent kafka and use schema registry into our cloudera environment. Thats actually a cool solution, I used twitter bijection and schema registry in java for a similar application. I am unable to install this python client.

Comment: give more details about kafkaParams, how does the parameters looks ?

Comment: please find the edited code above.

Comment: @Marie I am having trouble serializing the messages from kafka using this api..."raise SerializerError("message does not start with magic byte")" at /confluent/schemaregistry/serializers/MessageSerializer.py", line 180, in decode_message. Can anyone suggest any other solution or solve this issue. I am using [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33488147/8201517) in my consumer, where my producer is a springboot application which is using avro and twitter bijection.