# Spark Streaming Kafka Consumer (Avro) - AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'split'

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka, avro

I'm trying to build a Spark Streaming App that consumes messages from a Kafka topic with messages formatted with Avro but I'm facing some troubles with the Confluent message deserializer.

Following the instructions from [Spark Python Avro Kafka Deserialiser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30339636/spark-python-avro-kafka-deserialiser) I got the Kafka consumer to deserialize the messages correctly, but end up failing to run the PythonStreamingDirectKafkaWordCount example.

**Code:**

```
import sys
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext
from pyspark.streaming.kafka import KafkaUtils
from confluent_kafka.avro.cached_schema_registry_client import CachedSchemaRegistryClient
from confluent_kafka.avro.serializer.message_serializer import MessageSerializer
schema_registry_client = CachedSchemaRegistryClient(url='http://127.0.0.1:8081')
serializer = MessageSerializer(schema_registry_client)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sc = SparkContext(appName="PythonStreamingDirectKafkaWordCount")
    ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 2)
    sc.setLogLevel("WARN")
    kvs = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(ssc, ["avrotest2"], {"metadata.broker.list": "localhost:9092"}, valueDecoder=serializer.decode_message)
    lines = kvs.map(lambda x: x[1])
    lines.pprint()
    counts = lines.flatMap(lambda line: line.split(" ")).map(lambda word: (word, 1)).reduceByKey(lambda a, b: a + b)
    counts.pprint()
    ssc.start()
    ssc.awaitTermination()
```

**Spark Submit CLI**

```
/opt/spark/bin/spark-submit --packages org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-kafka-0-8_2.11:2.0.0 --jars spark-streaming-kafka-0-8_2.11-2.0.0.jar smartbus-stream-app_avro2.py
```

**lines.pprint() output:**

```
{u'temperature': 21.0, u'max_capacity': 44, u'equip_type': u'Autocarro', u'id': u'CARRIS_502', u'tire_pressure': 4.974999904632568, u'humidity': 21.0, u'equip_category': u'Carruagem_Unica', u'users_out': 2.0, u'equip_brand': u'Volvo', u'battery_status': 99.5, u'equip_fuel': u'Biodiesel', u'fuel': 39.79999923706055, u'equip_model': u'3d', u'aqi_sensor': 5.0, u'seated_capacity': 32, u'users_in': 3.0, u'location': u'38.760780, -9.166853'}
```

**StackTrace output:**

```
2018-03-17 03:47:06 ERROR Executor:91 - Exception in task 0.0 in stage 36.0 (TID 29)
org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 229, in main
    process()
  File "/opt/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 224, in process
    serializer.dump_stream(func(split_index, iterator), outfile)
  File "/opt/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/rdd.py", line 2438, in pipeline_func
  File "/opt/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/rdd.py", line 2438, in pipeline_func
  File "/opt/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/rdd.py", line 362, in func
  File "/opt/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/rdd.py", line 1857, in combineLocally
  File "/opt/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/shuffle.py", line 236, in mergeValues
    for k, v in iterator:
  File "/root/ss_app/smartbus-stream-app_avro2.py", line 17, in <lambda>
    counts = lines.flatMap(lambda line: line.split(" ")).map(lambda word: (word, 1)).reduceByKey(lambda a, b: a + b)
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'split'

        at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.handlePythonException(PythonRunner.scala:298)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRunner.scala:438)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRunner.scala:421)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.hasNext(PythonRunner.scala:252)
        at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$GroupedIterator.fill(Iterator.scala:1126)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$GroupedIterator.hasNext(Iterator.scala:1132)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
        at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.write(BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.java:125)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:96)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:53)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:109)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:345)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Can't really find much more details on the matter. Can any expert shed some light on the issue?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you checked the data type of lines.it will dstream.

Answer (score 0):

It is throwing that error because you are trying to split the Dictonary. Inside the flat map each line is coming as dictionary.so when you  try to split it will throw this Error dict has no attribute split.