# Spark Stream - 'utf8' codec can't decode bytes

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, spark-streaming

I'm fairly new to stream programming. We have Kafka stream which use Avro.

I want to connect a Kafka Stream to Spark Stream. I used bellow code.

```
kvs = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(ssc, [topic], {"metadata.broker.list": brokers})
lines = kvs.map(lambda x: x[1])
```

I got bellow error.

> return s.decode('utf-8')
>     File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/encodings/utf_8.py", line 16, in decode
>       return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)
>   UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode bytes in position 57-58: invalid continuation byte

Do i need to specify that Kafka use Avro, Is above error for that? If it is how I can specify it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right, the problem is with deserialization of the stream. You can use  [confluent-kafka-python](https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-python) library and specify **valueDecoder** in :

```
from confluent_kafka.avro.cached_schema_registry_client import CachedSchemaRegistryClient`
from confluent_kafka.avro.serializer.message_serializer import MessageSerializer

kvs = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(ssc, [topic], {"metadata.broker.list": brokers}, valueDecoder=MessageSerializer.decode_message)`
```

Credits for the solution to https://stackoverflow.com/a/49179186/6336337

Comment: Hi Lev G, I think your answer is correct, but I had a another error after changes are made.

Comment: However i changed  serializer.decode_message to MessageSerializer.decode_message. Is it ok? New error: https://stackoverflow.com/q/52714436/8089635

Comment: Right, I fixed my answer - it should should be **MessageSerializer**. Please accept the answer

Comment: In Kafka we are using a Schema Registry, Shouldn't we need to specify it here?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you should specify it.

With java :

creation of stream :

```
final JavaInputDStream<ConsumerRecord<String, avroType>> stream =
                KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(
                        jssc,
                        LocationStrategies.PreferConsistent(),
                        ConsumerStrategies.Subscribe(topics, kafkaParams));
```

in the kafka consumer config :

```
kafkaParams.put("key.deserializer", org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer.class);
        kafkaParams.put("value.deserializer", SpecificAvroDeserializer.class);
```